# Looking to check if part of a user input can be in a range of integers

Tags: python-3.x

I'm fairly new to Python,
I'm trying to check if the user input can be checked in a range of integers
The following is the code I have already written

```
#LL DD LLL
#where L is a letter
#where D is a digit
#eg SG 61 ABC

area_codes = ["SG", "PV", "LJ", "EX"]

reg = input("Enter registration: ")
if reg[0:2] in area_codes:
    print(reg[0:2])
    if reg[2:3] in range(0,18):
            print(reg[2:3])
    else:
        print("nope")
```

And this is the response I am given,

```
Enter registration: SG15
SG
nope
```

How do I check this properly?
I have tried a few things but I don't even know if this is possible.

Thank you in advance,
Donberry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reg[2:3]` is a slice of your input string. So it's a number, but stored as string.

When you do:

```
if reg[2:3] in range(0,18):
```

you're checking if the string in contained in the `range` object (python 3) or `list` object (python 2) which contains *integers*. So the test fails every time.

Had you done

```
if 0 <= reg[2:3] < 18:
```

you'd have gotten an explicit error in python 3. Besides, it avoids to build a `range` or `list` object just for the sake of testing. Chained comparison like this is way faster.

So I'm suggesting:

```
if 0 <= int(reg[2:3]) < 18:
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the string to an integer before checking it's in the range. Also, (and I don't know if you did this), but you should verify that you want numbers between 0 and 17, which is what your code does.

That is, `range(0, 18)` - equivalent to `range(18)`, by the way - generates the list of numbers starting at 0 and ending at 17, including both 0 and 17.

Anyway, you would check it like this:

```
if int(reg[2:3]) in range(0,18):
        print(reg[2:3])
```

Comment: even better: `if 0 <= int(reg[2:3]) < 18:` saves building a `range` object, or `list` in python 2, but doesn't generate a list in python 3, just keeps it as a `range` object.

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you so much.